# Jquery - removing class by selecting element by same class $(.A).removeClass(.A)

Tags: jquery

I have some element, which have class A, for example

```
<a class="A">test</a>
```

then i trying to remove that class from the element:

```
$('.A').removeClass('.A');
```

But it seems not working, how to make it work if i know only a class of this element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must remove dot from parameter of `removeClass`, like this:

```
$('.A').removeClass('A');
```

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
$('.A').removeClass('A');
```